# python code error NameError: name 'lSimples' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Nodo:
    """docstring forNodo."""
    def __init__(self, nombre = None, materia= None, sig = None):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.materia= materia
        self.sig =  sig

    def __str__(self):
        return "% %" %(self.nombre, self.materia)

        class lSimples:
            """docstring forlSimple."""
            def __init__(self):

                self.cabeza = None
                self.cola = None

    def agregar(self, elemento):

        if self.cabeza == None:
            self.cabeza = elemento

        if self.cola != None:
            self.cola.sig = elemento

        self.cola = elemento

if __name__:str == "__main__"

ls = lSimples()
while(True):
    print("-----Menu------ \n"+
    "1. Agregar ")
    num = input("ingrese la opcion")

    if num == 1:
     nombre= input("ingrese el nombre: ")
     materia = input("ingrese la materia:")
     nod = Nodo(nombre, materia)
    ls.agregar(nod)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lSimples` class is defined inside Nodo class, and you are calling `lSimples class` from outside the `Nodo` class i.e from global scopes. Since the `lSimples` is inside `Nodo` and cannot be accessed from outside hence The `NameError` Occurred as there is no such thing `lSimples` in the outer scope.

I think this may help:

```
class Nodo:
"""docstring forNodo."""
    def __init__(self, nombre = None, materia= None, sig = None):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.materia= materia
        self.sig =  sig

    def __str__(self):
        return "% %" %(self.nombre, self.materia)

    class lSimples:
        """docstring forlSimple."""
        def __init__(self):

            self.cabeza = None
            self.cola = None

        def agregar(self, elemento):

            if self.cabeza == None:
                self.cabeza = elemento

            if self.cola != None:
                self.cola.sig = elemento

            self.cola = elemento

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ls = Nodo.lSimples()
    while(True):
        print("-----Menu------ \n"+"1. Agregar ")
        num = input("ingrese la opcion")

        if num == 1:
            nombre= input("ingrese el nombre: ")
            materia = input("ingrese la materia:")
            nod = Nodo(nombre, materia)
            ls.agregar(nod)
```

Comment: thanks so mucho, 
it was a syntax problem in my text editor

Answer (score 0):

because lSimples class is defined inside Nodo class, and you are calling lSimples class  from global environment